# Passing multidimensional array via function template

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++11, multidimensional-array

*^ Please explain how my question is a duplicate of the one you linked.*

I am trying to pass a multidimensional array into a function. The array looks something like this:

```
const char CHECKERS_ANIMATION[][8] = {
    {0xcc,0xcc,0x33,0x33,0xcc,0xcc,0x33,0x33},
    {0x33,0x33,0xcc,0xcc,0x33,0x33,0xcc,0xcc}
};
```

I have bunch of these arrays. They are all Nx8 where N is known at compile time.

In my class header file I have a public method defined as such:

```
template <typename T, size_t frames, size_t rows> void playAnimation(int device_number, const T (&animation)[frames][rows], int iterations = 1, int speed = 50000);
```

The implementation of this method:

```
template <typename T, size_t frames, size_t rows> void LEDMatrix::playAnimation(int device_number, const T (&animation)[frames][rows], int iterations, int speed)
{
cout << "r: " << rows << ", f: " << frames << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < frames; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++) {
            putRow(device_number, k, animation[j][k]);
        }

        usleep(speed);
        clearDisplay(device_number);
    }
}
}
```

The method is called as such:

```
obj->playAnimation(0, CHECKERS_ANIMATION);
```

I picked this approach, because I need to know the NxM size of the array inside the method.

When I compile this I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccMH2CBE.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text.startup+0x44): undefined reference to `void LEDMatrix::playAnimation<char, 13u, 8u>(int, char const (&) [13u][8u], int, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I resolve this? I have already killed two days trying to solve what I think is a simple problem.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to put the implemention of the template function in the header file (as explained in the linked question)

Comment: There's lot of mixed information out there. Some say you don't have to do it in .h, some say you do.

Comment: There are a very few cases where you can get away without putting it in the header. But dir the moment, just do it.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to find another solution, since putting it into the header is not what I want to do.